# How would you design a power divider with 50-Ohm unbalanced input and 4x 100-Ohm balanced output impedances to send RF down a CAT6 cable?

Tags: power, rf, filter, impedance, passive-networks

A CAT6 cable has 4 balanced pairs, each at 100 Ohm.  I'm wondering if I can make a 50-Ohm coax unbalanced input and split the power to 4x 100-Ohm balanced output (and then merge it back together the same way on the other side).

How would you design a power divider with a 50-Ohm input and 100-Ohm outputs?  This is not an "uneven-power" splitter: we want the power split to be the equal, just change the port impedances and switch from unbalanced to balanced (and back on the other end of the cable).

- Can a power splitter like this be realized without a balun?  There exist [microstrip unbalanced-to-balanced power splitters](https://www.jpier.org/PIERC/pierc76/05.17061503.pdf) without an obvious balun, but can it be done with lumped elements?
- How do you generalize an N-Way splitter where the input impedance is different from the output impedance in terms of R/L/C values for the circuit? (but maybe start with a 2- or 3-port example?)

Comment: Why use a splitter if they are equal 100 ohm loads

Comment: A 'Wilkinson' has equal input and output impedances, so something else is not a Wilkinson. Perhaps you mean a splitter having some of the other Wilkinson propoerties? The main thing about a 'wilky' is the port to port isolation, that you've not mentioned, that's different in other splitter designs. Perhaps you'd present a full matrix of the power transfer between all ports so that we can see what you want in this new unnamed splitter.

Comment: @Neil_UK, I updated the question to be more detailed.  I was going to break these into two questions, but maybe it makes sense to put my thoughts all in the same place.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, because I meant to mention, that it must also be unbalanced-to-balanced.  I updated the question with more detail...

Comment: What do you hope to gain?  If each pair gives say 20dB loss, splitting the signal across 4 pairs and combining still gives 20dB loss.  Are you trying to increase the power handling?

Comment: What fractional bandwidth do you want to operate over? Transformers fairly wideband, LCs and microstrip can be made wideband with multiple stages, basic Wilky and other single stage designs are quite narrowband.

Comment: @Tesla23, power handling was what I was thinking, but I didn't realize the loss was so high.  -20dB over 100m for a single strand 23 awg.  This was a curiosity, but perhaps not worth perusing.  Was thinking I could replace expensive coax with leftover shielded cat6.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, what do you mean by "Why use a splitter if they are equal 100 ohm loads"? The question is about tying 4x 100-ohm balanced to 1x 50-ohm unbalanced.  Are you hinting at something brilliant that "just works" and I'm missing it?